# General 3D Graphics

Tags: discussion

After seeing [How can we ensure Blender.SE doesn't share 3DGraphics.SE's fate?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-can-we-ensure-blender-se-doesnt-share-3dgraphics-ses-fate)

Are questions regarding general, or theoretic, 3D concepts on-topic?

e.g.

- Best lighting for a specific set
- How to make sure the render keeps the depth perception
- How does the computer handle models mathematically

Maybe not best examples, but it's what I came up with.

Answer (score 8):

Try not to ask subjective questions or ones that are too open to interpretation or likely to start a discussion.

### - Best lighting for a specific set?

This is too broad and the title is extremely vague. There will be numerous ways of doing it if the answers are to relate to the question, and as the OP you might end up not approving any of them.

Instead you could ask **Which lamps are better for lighting an indoor nighttime set?**

### - How to make sure the render keeps the depth perception?

This is ok, the scope is immediately set, you are asking a question on rendering settings. Fine.

### - How does the computer handle models mathematically?

Off-topic, this is highly technical and does not directly ask how its done in Blender. Too general IMO.

You could instead ask **How does the Blender parse and handle wavefront object files?**

The key thing to keep in mind here is to always ask specifics and be as explicit or clear as possible. If someone has too think too much about what you are asking, you are less likely to get a good answer. CG questions that are too general would not be ideal. Try to have your question ask as to how something can be done using Blender, as that's what the site is about.

Comment: Regarding the last - it can help with scripting

Comment: @JNF how can *knowing how the computer handle models mathematically* help with scripting?. There are dozens of model formats, each with their own quirks and cons. It is not only off-topic but broad.

Comment: Computing volume, for instance. I mean math and algorithms for working with 3d data

Comment: I think, as this answer said, that if the question is sufficient specific it will be welcome. A question that is generic (meaning generic as doable in others CG programs) but that make users to answers specifics to Blender would be ok.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is wise to begin accepting questions that aren't related to Blender - at least at this point.

Most general/theoretical/conceptual questions can probably be related to Blender in some way. If they can't, they should be closed as off topic. I'd imagine that many of these questions wouldn't be suitable for other reasons as well (e.g. not constructive or too broad).

It would be really sad to see this site go down the same path as [3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics), which also started out at as a [Blender proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/5022/revisions):

> The proposal started
>   out as a Blender site, and grew in scope over time until by launch
>   its focus was unrecognizable - there's a very good chance it simply
>   overshot its target audience. It's also quite possible that in the
>   nearly year and a half incubation period, the folks who *might*
>   have made up a core group of experts simply lost interest.

Comment: I think we have a fair shot, the community is more motivated. Lots of new features in Blender and plenty of other sites that stick to one topic have been successful, askubuntu for one.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

I think, at least at the moment, there seems no other place to ask such questions. Even if it would be acceptable in another place, this is probably the best place to do it.

These questions are of interest for the community even if they don't necessarily involve Blender.