# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We recently entered public beta and while it's still very early, our stats are a bit lacking compared to what they could be, they could at least correlate with the number of users. At the time of writing [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40377/blender) is reporting.

### 173 visits/day

This site has amazing potential for becoming *The* Blender Resource. It's fresh and is a refreshing take from IRC and confusing threads in forums. We need everyone to start help promoting the site. This site is geared towards anyone who uses Blender, be it a professional, enthusiast or complete beginner.

*Taken from my answer on [How can we ensure Blender.SE doesn't share 3DGraphics.SE's fate?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-can-we-ensure-blender-se-doesnt-share-3dgraphics-ses-fate)*

> There are several variables involved but the major one is **publicity**.
>   Even in our commitment phase which took nearly a year, I myself had no
>   idea of it until I randomly stumbled across it. What we need is
>   publicity. *IIRC* every Blender release totals around at least 200k
>   downloads which means that there are lots of people out there, people
>   who want to learn.

Some of us have the resources but lack the general know how to go about it.

---

Several users have already pledged to helping to promote this site to their fanbase or specific community. This is a good start, users like [Jonathan Williamson](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/44/jonathan-williamson) from [BlenderCooke](http://cgcookie.com/blender/) and [CharlesL](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20/charlesl) from [TheSpasticKangaroo](http://www.youtube.com/thespastickangaroo) on Youtube. You might not be as popular as them but every bit counts.

Let's make this a great community. We are already doing very well with over **100 questions** and over **200 answers**!

All that being said, **What are some good ways that we can actively promote our community and spread the word about this site?**

Comment: i'm a little confused as to why this hasn't appeared in Blender Nation or on Ton's twitter feed :)

Comment: @zeffii hence the post.. we need shares! :)

Comment: @Charles [just posted it to Blender nation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9669896#9669896).

Comment: [“Meet the pros” scheduled chat with Jonathan Williamson](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/90/14)

Comment: One little thing we can all do is put a link to blender.SE in our signatures on other Blender sites, like BlenderArtists. It's not major publicity, but it'll draw people in over time.

Comment: Ton just tweeted it. Take shelter!

Comment: @zeffii Who's Ton?

Comment: @DantheMan He's probably referring to [Ton Roosendaal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ton_Roosendaal), one of the core devs and project lead for Blender.

Comment: @greatwolf Haha. Yeah. I just found out the other day.

Comment: I created a video for TheSpasticKangaroo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWUSJUpGTv8 telling about the new Blender.SE site. I plan on mentioning it at the end of future videos for a while also.

Comment: @CharlesL excellent!

Answer (score 6):

Actively tweeting interesting questions and answers, I also submitted a story to [/r/blender](http://redd.it/1fdcwq) over on Reddit's Blender subchannel. *(wonder how many downvotes it will get ;)*

*Also from my answer on [How can we ensure Blender.SE doesn't share 3DGraphics.SE's fate?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/how-can-we-ensure-blender-se-doesnt-share-3dgraphics-ses-fate)*

> My main suggestion is to share the site wherever and whenever you can,
>   tweet a well written question or answer you found useful and or share
>   a new tip or trick you learnt via your social and personal pages.
>   Invite or tell a friend.

**Update**:
Spoke to the guys over on reddit in [/r/blender](http://www.reddit.com/r/blender/) and we are now featured as the goto site for technical help etc.

Comment: we might also change all blender tags on different SE sites to inform users that there is a blenderSE site

Comment: @miceterminator its in planning, we should have a meta post fron GraphicDesign.SE soon for questions we can take, the rest will come in time.

Answer (score 6):

It might help a little that it is now on [blender](http://blender.org)'s **front page!**

It is in the Official Updates from Blender Foundation, which means it will probably be there awhile.

[image: Blender's Front Page]

Comment: Yep, for anyone curious. http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/138/12 and https://twitter.com/tonroosendaal/status/343383578836615168

Comment: that is how I found this site, [this](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/06/10/blender-stack-exchange/) post on BN

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying my best to get the word out there.

Creating filters and sharing on social networks

http://stackexchange.com/filters/93031/blender-python

Posting rss feeds on Facebook pages, for example

https://www.facebook.com/LearningBlender2.5

Adding Flair badges on blogs

http://learningblender3dsoftware.blogspot.in/p/about.html

Note: The former is a page that I administer and the latter is my Blender blog. I hope in this context it is fine for me to post my own links..

Comment: nice! :) Our stats have significantly increased since then! See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40377/blender but every bit still is helping!

Comment: :) Interesting link. Nice overview of stats.