# Pro-Tempore Moderator Nominations

Tags: discussion, moderation

Well, we've made it out of the rough, *(Private Beta)* and are well on our way into the Public Beta gaining more and more users daily. According to the [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), the SE Team will pick up (usually 3) users to become Moderators more or less a week into Public Beta, until we graduate, so I think we can start with nominations. After graduation there will be actual elections where users can nominate and vote.

Please read the following *carefully..*

### As per the blog post, Moderators should:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

### Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

### Additional Info

- **You can self-nominate or nominate others.** Each nomination should be posted as a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so everyone can see their activity. Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.
- If the nomination was posted by a 3rd-party, the nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.

*Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections after the Beta period.*

Answer (score 12):

I would like to nominate myself..

**Main**

[image: profile for iKlsR at Blender Stack Exchange, Q&A for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

**Meta**

[image: profile for iKlsR at Blender Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

[Some of the promotion](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/96/12) I have done.

- I am familiar with a very large portion of Blender, from its codebase and history to it's modeling and compositing tools etc.
- I don't work at the moment *(finishing up my CS degree)* so I can easily dedicate several hours daily to the site.
- My timezone allows me be around when the other mods more than likely won't be UTC 00:00 is 7pm here.

All that being said, I am very interested in the future of this site and wish to be a central part of it. Good luck to everyone else!

Answer (score 11):

**Main**

[image: profile for ideasman42 at Blender Stack Exchange, Q&A for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

**Meta**

[image: profile for ideasman42 at Blender Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

[Blender development log](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/WhatImWorkingOn)

I would like to nominate myself..

- I'm a blender developer and have used blender professionally in previous jobs.
- I've been involved with some of the open-movie projects, so have worked with small groups on projects and had experience helping artists.
- I've been involved with GSOC and mentoring students since GSOC started.

I use stackoverflow for development questions and am happy this site is becoming available for blender users.

Answer (score 6):

**Main:**

[image: profile for CharlesL at Blender Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

**Meta**
[image: profile for CharlesL at Blender Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

**Area 51**

[Area 51 profile for CharlesL http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/61430.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/61430/charlesl)

I would like to nominate myself:

- I have tons of experience with Blender and have been working with it since 2.49a
- Even though I'm mainly a blender artist ([portfolio](http://behance.net/ninjacharliestudio)), I have technical skills also (I know how to program in python)
- I know how to answer questions clearly and concisely as I have a successful YouTube channel where I teach Blender tutorials(http://youtube.com/thespastickangaroo) (I also make sure to let my subscribers know about Blender Stack exchange on my channel).
- I'm in high school, so I have free time to put into this site(I already put about 3 hours into the site every day and spend a lot of the day on chat).
- Throughout the beta, I've been very active to answer questions/edit posts/vote.

Anyway, I hope this site is extremely successful as I believe it will be an awesome resource to Blender users.

Answer (score 5):

**Main**

[image: Profile for Gwenn at Blender Stack Exchange, Q&A for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

**Meta**

[image: Profile for iKlsR at Blender Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

I would like to nominate myself.

- I am very experienced with the technical side of Blender, having seven years of experience coding in Python
- I am particularly experienced with all parts of the modeling process in Blender, having used these tools in an architectural context professionally for several years
- I can, and do, dedicate a significant amount of my time to this site

I am very excited to see this site develop, and I want to do everything possible to help it become a successful part of the larger Blender community. Here's what I have done for the community so far:

- I have read every single question posted on this site
- I actively work to develop and promote good ideas, as evidenced by my voting, commenting, reviewing, and editing rates on the Blender beta. I am the top voter on the site
- I am on the site for 13 hours every weekday (from 15:00 to 4:00 UTC), and am very often the first to comment on or answer new posts

Whether I am elected as a moderator or not, I will do everything I can to help this site grow and establish itself as a valuable resource for the entire Blender community.

Answer (score 4):

**Main**

[image: profile for Dan the Man at Blender Stack Exchange, Q&A for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

**Meta**

[image: profile for Dan the Man at Blender Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

**Area 51**

[Area 51 profile for Dan the Man http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/42395.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/42395/dan-the-man)

I would like to nominate myself:

- Have experience with beta sites ([History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/16/dan-the-man)).
- I have been using Blender since version 2.47 in 2008.
- I'm pretty familiar with every aspect of Blender, except video editing and I'm currently learning scripting.
- I have spare time to invest into this site. I'm finishing up high school, and then probably going to study computer science.
- I'm constantly editing questions and answers to make them more legible and to have appropriate tags.
- Will try with enthusiasm (even if not a moderator) to get this site out of beta. I started the "Meet the Pros" chat events.

Answer (score 4):

**Main.sequence(star):**

[image: profile for RolandiXor at Blender Stack Exchange, Q&A for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

**Meta:**

[image: profile for RolandiXor at Blender Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games]

**Area51:** *(I wasn't the alien that crashed there, sorry).*

[Area 51 profile for RolandiXor http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/29867.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/29867/rolandixor)

**Global Stats:**

[profile for RolandiXor on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/243378.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/243378)

I would like to nominate myself for the role:

- I have a relatively good grasp of Blender and have been using it since about 2.32 (possibly earlier) or so.
- I am not a Blender "expert" by some standards, but I think this helps to have good understanding of the position of the average user as opposed to only seeing things from the "professional" perspective.
- I have actively promoted the site since I knew about its proposal.
- I'm a moderator on Askubuntu, so I'm familiar with the mod tools and the duties of a moderator.
- I spend a lot of time on the chat during the week when I can, and pop on to the site often during the day (I don't time myself, sorry) to check for questions/answers, review tasks, and tags.
- This is a kitten.
  [image: Secret weapon]
  Therefore you should vote for me.